# Change dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report already created with a dataset, however I need to delete a column from the Group. Is there a way to change the dataset query once the report is already built?

Comment: Open the data set, change the query, then hit the refresh fields button, handle any errors raised, ensure that the column isn't referenced in groups, sort orders, drill through actions, filters, report headers/ footers, etc.  It won't deploy if there is an error in it, but sometimes it takes a bit of detective work to find out where the error actually comes from.  Use the "Run" mode as you will get a more comprehensive error than you would elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit that on your .rdl file. After updating it, you just overwrite the report on your server.